# How to put pagenumber on first page?

Tags: page-numbering, pagestyle

I am using `\pagestyle{plain}` to print page numbers but on the first page it just doesn't get printed.

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) We are flattered that you think we can read minds `:-)` but, unfortunately, most of us can't and we actually need to look at some code. Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this way we can copy-paste the code and look at the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you are doing.

Comment: Probably because you are using a document class that intentionally omit the page number in the title page (where it is really useless) but without the MWE ... `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't bothered to show us your code I'm making a wild guess that you might be using the `report` or `book` class with a `\maketitle`. The default for these is to put the title on an unnumbered page. You can change this by using the class option `notitlepage`.

```
% firstpageprob.tex  SE 575504

\documentclass[notitlepage]
  {report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{TITILLATION}
\author{Anonymous}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```